# JAVA have calling method wait for activity in JFrame to complete

Tags: java, swing

Currently I am calling a method (showFrames) which pops up a JFrame which contains many editable text fields. I am storing the value of these text fields in a list (editedFields) which I need to use in the calling method. My issue is that my calling method is not waiting for the user to select ok/cancel before continuing so the list is not populated when I am trying to take action on it. I tried to overcome this by using a modal dialog to no avail. the method is being called here...

```
...
showFrames(longToShortNameMap);
if (editedFields != null) {
     for (JTextField field : editedFields) {
          System.out.println(field.getText());
     }
}
...
```

and the showFrames method is implemented as:

```
private static void showFrames(Map<String, String> longToShortNameMap) {
    final ToolDialog frame = new ToolDialog("Data Changed");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setModal(true);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 500);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 0));
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList(longToShortNameMap.keySet());
    final List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String key : keys) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(key);
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(longToShortNameMap.get(key));
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(textField);
        textFields.add(textField);
    }
    JButton okButton = new JButton("OK"); //added for ok button
    okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            editedFields = textFields;
            frame.setVisible(false);
            frame.dispose();

        }
    });
    JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");//added for cancel button
    cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.setVisible(false);
            frame.dispose();

        }
    });
    okButton.setVisible(true);//added for ok button
    cancelButton.setVisible(true);//added for cancel button
    buttonPanel.add(okButton);//added for ok button
    buttonPanel.add(cancelButton);//added for cancel button
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);

    scrollPane.setVisible(true);
    scrollPane.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

the current behavior I observe is that when the JFrame pops up, all the fields will immediately print out instead of waiting for the user to click "OK". Effectively this means I am receiving the default values in the text fields instead of the edited values.

Note: ToolDialog extends JDialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem that you have is that you are instantiating the Dialog first, making it visible, and then adding fields to it.

That is essentially incorrect.  All objects should be added to it while you are instantiating the Frame/Dialog, preferably in the constructor call.  Then, you make it visible when everything is ready.

Of course, you can add a new field to the frame after showing it already, but that is typically done based on some event, for example, when user clicks "Add a new number", then you add new text fields, etc to it.

So, the fix for you is simple, move the logic that adds the buttons, the lists, the panels etc, to the constructor, and then make that window visible.

Comment: move the logic to what contructor? This is a little ambiguous can you provide an example

Comment: The code starting with "JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));" to "  frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);"

Essentially all of that code is just "constructing" your ToolDialog.  So, it should be in the ToolDialog constructor.

Comment: yes what constructor are you saying to move this to though I'm not sure what youre talking about

Comment: As an alternative, you could also simply move the "frame.setVisible(true)" to much later, to the very last line of your posted code.  Up until that point, you are still creating the frame, so why show it..

Comment: moving the setvisible call to the very last line of the showFrames method worked, thank you. Is this because modality will block everything from being added after visibility is set to true?

Comment: ``JFrame#setVisible(boolean)`` actually *shows* (hides) the frame. Settings like modality needs to be assigned *before* displaying.

Comment: @peggy, I am glad it worked.  The best way is to keep your constructor clean:  1. Add all fields (panes, panels, what not).  2. Set the modality.  3. Show the window.  (The mnemonic for these steps may not be that good, but but let that not dissuade you!)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different issues here :

1. Waiting for a dialog.
2. Displaying the dialog correctly.

**1.- Waiting for a dialog.**

You should use a JDialog <strike>instead of a JFrame</strike> to make the window modal.

The window is not modal because you are showing it before setting it to modal. See [JDialog.setModal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal(boolean)) :

> Note: changing modality of the visible dialog may have no effect until
> it is hidden and then shown again.

You need to switch theese two lines :

```
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setModal(true);
```

An alternate way is to synchronize with a countdown latch:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
.......
showFrames(longToShortNameMap);
latch.await(); // suspends thread util dialog calls latch.countDown
if (editedFields != null) {
.......
/// Dialog code
latch.countDown(); // place it everywhere you are done with the dialog.
dispose();
```

**2.- Displaying the dialog correctly.**

Place `frame.setVisible(true)` as the last line of `showFrames`.

Comment: I've improved the answer. Setting the Dialog to modal is really the issue.

Comment: i have moved the setVisible call to after the setModal call which produces an empty, unsized ToolDialog

Comment: no, it produced a black JFrame with no scroll pane or buttons in it

Comment: I've tested your code and indeed does not show a proper dialog. Moving setVisible to the end solves it.

Comment: +1 for your time and attention however the only portion of this answer which solves the problem is your section labeled "2.-Displaying the dialog correctly"